# Help understanding 腸捻転エビ固めモミ手返し

Tags: translation, expressions

The following sentence is baffling me:

> 頭が腸捻転エビ固めモミ手返しを喰ったようで「明日にでも実家に帰らせて頂きマス」とか「私の前世は『枯野の宿』だった」とか口走りかねない。

I think I understand the ending (but please let me know if anything is mistranslated):

> 「明日にでも実家に帰らせて頂きマス」とか「私の前世は『枯野の宿』だった」とか口走りかねない: It wasn't unlike me to blurt out things like, "May I go visit my parents tomorrow?" or "*Kareno no Yado* was my former life."

Is the beginning portion something to the effect of "While rubbing my hands together and eating shrimp out of their shells..."?

Any help and insight you could provide me with would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is this a wife whose husband was pleading/apologizing about something but then did something to betray that? If not, a little more context would help.

Comment: This is from the biography of a famous taiko performer. He is reflecting on the point in time when the performing group he was in started to change (new management, etc.) and go in a new direction, and he wasn't really on board with it.

Here's the full paragraph:

「太鼓を打つ」という事は、「どういう事になるのか?」この頃も全くわかってはいない。だから節操がなくなるし、信念などは持てない。ようするに未知なる世界が広がってゆくばかりなのだ。しかし、逆説でいえば、わからない部分がわかってくるという事は、少しずつ「わかってきた」部分があるとわかってきたという事にもなる。いや、待てよ。頭が腸捻転エビ固めモミ手返しを喰ったようで「明日にでも実家に帰らせて頂きマス」とか「私の前世は『枯野の宿』だった」とか口走りかねない。とにかく、太鼓を叩いて世界を旅している事は確かな事なのだから、運動の第三法則すなわち作用・反作用の法則を復習しながら、浦島太郎の相対性理論による旅の七転八起を深酒してゆきたい。と近頃おもっている。

Comment: わからない部分がわかってくるという事は、少しずつ「わかってきた」部分があるとわかってきたという事にもなる this part is completely gibberish to me... =D

Comment: I settled on this: "However, to put it paradoxically, in order to understand something that I do not understand, I must recognize that the knowledge I do have now, I came upon gradually over time." But, that took me a long time and I'm not confident in it at all, haha. Plus, he does say "No, wait..." in the next sentence, leading me to believe it's suppose to be gibberish-esque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's basically a nonsense joke. 腸捻転エビ固めモミ手返し is his own made-up word which just sounds like some [attack/move of professional wrestling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_wrestling_attacks).

- 腸捻転【ちょうねんてん】: [volvolus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volvulus) or "intestine twister" (I think there's no such attack in reality)
- エビ固【がた】め: [逆エビ固め (boston crab)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%86%E3%82%A8%E3%83%93%E5%9B%BA%E3%82%81)
- モミ手: hand-rubbing
- 返し: counter-attack, counter-move

So it's something like "intestine-twisting boston-crab hand-rubbing counter-attack", but each word is not really important.

喰う/食う in this context is "to take (an attack)".

His head was so confused as if he took this strange "attack", that he almost said those meaningless sentences like 実家に帰ります/前世は宿だった.

Comment: Thank you! This makes much more sense. Linking to the wrestling move especially was really helpful.